# Xamarain iOS - Binding a library that only has ARMv7 architecture - what will be my issues?

Tags: ios, architecture, xamarin, xamarin-studio, ios-library

I'm creating a binding for a library that I do not have access to the source for. It was built only for ARMv7. 
First issue: 
It will not work in the simulator - this is obvious, but the problem is that if I compile and run to the simulator Xamarin will break at that code and stop the simulator. Plus it crashes. Did I do something wrong with the binding or is this the way it is and I have to put in a conditional to ignore the commands? We're trying to turn the library into a binding for general use. So it would be nice if somehow I could put this condition in the binding DLL.

Second issue: 
I'm concerned this library will not work on 64-bit architecture via Xamarin since it is only compiled with ARMv7. Can anyone confirm or refute this? The library works with 64-bit builds as we have used it before with other app engines.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I think that [Apple will no longer let you submit an app if it doesn't support 64 bit](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a). I've always included 64bit binaries when submitting so I can't be certain.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also assuming this will be the issue. We updated an app in April so maybe the library was OK because of the deadline for updated apps. What I find strange is that even though we built with ARMv7 and x64 the library seems to work on devices with either architecture. I would have thought that it wouldn't on 64-bit devices.